# Clickable action for plotly histogram in python

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I have a plotly stacked histogram like this:

[image: histogram]

I would like to click one part of the graph(for instance, one blue part) and get the data for that part for another graph. I have tried the callback function: `def update_point(trace, points, selector)`

It seems to work fine with barplot and scatterplot but not with histogram. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please add minimum code to help others understand your problem and being able to help.

Comment: Where is the implementation of `update_point` function?